# What is the difference between PDO and MySQLi prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

What is the difference between these two `prepared` statements?

## 1

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

## 2

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

i checked many courses about prepared statements but the only one i understood was the 2nd way, since it could be written in procedural, Isn't it the same as PDO? since both of them are Prepared statements? Is there any speed difference or ease of use between them? I learnt the 2nd way because i thought PreparedStatment = PDO but i was shocked when i knew that it is not PDO, using

```
mysqli_prepare
mysqli_stmt_bind_param
mysqli_stmt_execute
mysqli_stmt_bind_result
```

Comment: The PDO version can be used with many other Database Engines the same way without needing to change any code. Other differences are minor

Comment: @HankyPanky Since i'm using PhpMyAdmin, I really don't know about the Database Engines, Will i need for example: If my DB reached big size to change from MariaDB to MongoDB or things like that? And would that need PDO instead of the MySQLi? To be more clear, Will i ever need any other Database Engines for my Website?

Comment: Nope you will never be forced to change database engines like that. It will be a design question and by the time you reach mysql performance limitations you'll be talking billions of rows. But just in case some other project requires some other database engine you will be able to program it better if you know 1 library that can talk to both the same way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is below:-

1. `Mysqli` is only for the MySQL database. `PDO` supports other database using the same functions.
2. `Mysqli` can be used in either an object-oriented style or a procedural style. `PDO` is always object-oriented.
3. `Mysqli` supports prepared statements with `?` placeholders for parameters. `PDO` supports both `?` placeholders and also named placeholders,  like `:columnName`.
4. For older PHP versions `Mysqli` only allowed explicit binding. Nowadays both `PDO` and `Mysqli` allow to simply pass an array of parameter values as you execute the prepared statement. Besides, since 8.2 `Mysqli` has [a handy function to run prepare and execute in one go](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query.php).

Comment: Tried to check courses with object-oriented style but they never explain how does it work, Now after thinking about that, Does object-oriented style need a special course to learn it? i really liked procedural style because it is really explanatory.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious from thecode you wrote it seems you already can use OOP style. what's the problem then?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The only code i wrote were the 3rd example in procedural style. 1 & 2 are copied.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious well if you need a whole course just to do a transition like `mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);` -> `$mysqli->query($sql);` then I don't know. May be there is one, try to search on google

Comment: this "->" really grinds my gears, But i understood from this example.